# Publish error again, error: 0x80880253

Tags: visual-studio

I recently repaired Visual Studio 2005 after getting a publish error.

Now I get the following error. How do I fix it?

> Error  2  SignTool reported an error 'Failed to sign bin\Release\TBRHelp.publish\setup.exe. SignTool Error: ISignedCode::Sign returned error: 0x80880253
>
> The signer's certificate is not valid for signing.
>
> SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Release\TBRHelp.publish\setup.exe

Answer (score 12):

I had this exact same problem last week. To solve this problem in Visual Studio 2008, I did the following:

1. I right clicked on the project and selected *Properties*.
2. Then I clicked on tag *Signing*.
3. Then I checked the checkbox next to *Sign the ClickOnce manifests*.
4. Then I pressed the button *Create Test Certificate...* and followed the process.

This worked for me, I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio 2008. When clicked on Signer les manifestes ClickOnce, I saw: `Date d'expiration on 16/03/2014. Today's is 25/03/2014.`

I didn't create a new certificate, but clicked on **"A partir du magasin"** and followed instructions.
I arrived to a certificate with expiration date at `02/06/2014,` from Toshiba... (The name of my computer). I imported it and my date date of the 'expiration change from `16/03/2014` to `02/06/2014`.

How can I have an automatic updated certificate date?